# Regex : several blocs, variable number of lines

Tags: regex

Here is my issue : I try to extract 2.0 corresponding the `/amountC/` of bloc `/id="two"/`. A bloc always have a "amountC" but may not have "amountA", B or D.

So I'd need to parse : `[any nb of cars or \n] bloc id="two" [any nb of cars or \n] amountC`

( I already have the regex to parse the number )

exemple of data to parse :

```
bloc id="one" {
"amountA" : 10.98,
"amountB" : 8.0,
"amountC" : 9.0,
"amountD" : 111.98
},
bloc id="two" {
"amountA" : 1.98,
"amountC" : 2.0,
"amountD" : 3.98
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with the formatting capabilities of the editor. For example, a code block should be indented by four spaces (highlight it and press Ctrl-K). Then, this doesn't look like a job for a regex. A JSON parser seems to be the correct tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe the context in which you are using the regex. As noted in a comment, if the content is JSON, you should probably use a JSON parser. I will try to answer the literal question you asked, however.

In most contexts, regex doesn't work well across multiple records (aka lines).  You could use `awk` or `sed` as a filter if you're running from the command line. Assuming the content were in a file named "content" you  could use the following:

**sed**

```
sed -E '1,/bloc id="two"/ { /bloc id="two"/ ! d }
        /.*"amountC" :/ {
             s/.*"amountC" *: *([0-9\.]+).*$/\1/
             q
        }' <content
```

1. Invoke `sed` with extended regex support. Delete all lines up to `bloc id="two"` (in case `"amountC"` occurs on the same line).
2. Now, look for the line containjng `"amountC"`.
3. Strip everything before and after the number (this example should more rigorously parse for a valid number).
4. Since `"amountC"` was already incurred, we are done; quit.
5. Direct content to the `sed` filter.

**awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN { Ignore=1 }
     /bloc id="two"/ { Ignore=0 }
     Ignore==1 { next }
     /"amountC"/ {
        print gensub(/.*"amountC" *: *([0-9\.]+).*/,"\\1")
        quit
     }
     // { next }' content
```

1. Invoke `awk` and initialize a flag to ignore lines.
2. If the `bloc id="two"` is incurred, start looking for "amountC".
3. Ignore leading lines (before `bloc id="two"`).
4. If `bloc id="two"` incurred, look for "amountC".
5. If target line found, output its numeric value.
6. Target found, so we're done.
7. (Close block)
8. If not the target line, skip to next line.